# How do you use sum and range values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to know how to sum and use range values in Python.

Let's say I want to use something like this:

```
 You rolled 12 dices. The numbers are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11.
 Would you like to score the points for all different numbers (50 points)?
```

And how would I score the points for all numbers?

I know about `for n in range(12):` and `random.randint(1,12)` but I am not very good in Python and would like some help with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you asking what the Python function for sum is? It is `sum`, which can be fed a list. If that isn't what you are asking, just what are you asking? Have you worked through a tutorial on Python? It might help you understand how basic things like lists work.

Comment: @JohnColeman, how do I use ```sum``` though? I've seen so many examples that start with ```sum=0```, is that it? I just would like to know how to use sum and range values in a code in Python.

Comment: If e.g. `rolls` is a list of numbers in the range 1-6, then `sum(rolls)` would be their sum, with no need for looping. It really isn't a bad idea to work through a book or tutorial. See this: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers for a list of resources.

Comment: @johncoleman, ok thanks. 

So as a example of range 1-6, would it be this?: ```list(range(6))```
```nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]```?

Comment: @BeR No it would be `list(range(1, 6))` since you want it to start with one

Comment: @u10-forward, thanks for correcting me. What else do I do? Do I do a print message with sum(rolls)?

Comment: @BeR Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a good task with numpy.

First you should decide how many dice they want to use and how many edges they want to have on each die. Then you should roll the dice and get output for each die according to the number of edges (there will be repetition to simulate real world scenario). Lastly, you ask if they want to sum and if so do it for them using `np.sum()`.

**Full code:**

```
import numpy as np

num_dice = int(input("How many dice would you like to roll? "))
dice_sides = int(input("How many sides per die? "))

while num_dice <= 0 or dice_sides <=0:
    if num_dice <= 0:
        num_dice = int(input("Invalid number of dice, enter a number greater than or equal to 1."))
    else:
        dice_sides = int(input("Invalid number of sides, enter a number greater than or equal to 1."))

rolled_nums = np.random.choice(range(1, dice_sides), size=num_dice, replace=True)
# If you don't want the brackets around the numbers produced by the dice rolling, 
# use ", ".join(str(i) for i in list(rolled_nums)) instead of list(rolled_nums) here.
print("You rolled {} dices. The numbers are {}.".format(num_dice, list(rolled_nums)))

decision = input("Would you like to sum the points for all the rolled numbers? (y/n) -> ")
if decision == 'y' or decision == 'Y':
    print("Total sum of all the rolled numbers is: {}".format(np.sum(rolled_nums)))
else:
    quit()
```

**Some notes to make:**

1. You have to make sure that the user enters reasonable inputs (values greater than 0) or else your calculation is not defined.
   This is done with the while loop to avoid just a single check.
2. Also, notice the use of `format()` in `print()` which helps keep your commands cleaner. I highly recommend using it as with more complex code, it will be a life saver. Check it out here for more details: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-format-function/
3. If you don't want the brackets around the numbers produced by the dice rolling, use `", ".join(str(i) for i in list(rolled_nums))` instead of `list(rolled_nums)`. This is indicated in the code with a comment

**Edit:** 
If you don't like numpy, here is the same functionality using just `import random`.

```
import random

num_dice = int(input("How many dice would you like to roll? "))
dice_sides = int(input("How many sides per die? "))

while num_dice <= 0 or dice_sides <=0:
    if num_dice <= 0:
        num_dice = int(input("Invalid number of dice, enter a number greater than or equal to 1."))
    else:
        dice_sides = int(input("Invalid number of sides, enter a number greater than or equal to 1."))

# Roll the dice one at a time and store their values
rolled_nums = []
for _ in range(num_dice):
  rolled_nums.append(random.choice(range(1, dice_sides)))

print("You rolled {} dices. The numbers are {}.".format(num_dice, rolled_nums))

decision = input("Would you like to sum the points for all the rolled numbers? (y/n) -> ")
if decision == 'y' or decision == 'Y':
    print("Total sum of all the rolled numbers is: {}".format(sum(rolled_nums)))
else:
    quit()
```

Again, you can remove the brackets from the list of numbers using the method described above (point 3.)

Comment: Hey, I tested out your code and saw that it worked - however I think this is too complex for me and that the code I'm learning is only requesting ```import random```, thus ```random.randint(1,12)```, is there any way you would be willing to edit that?

Comment: You want to import random rather than import numpy?

Comment: Numpy is very powerful for operations on mathematical structures (which might be very useful for you), but ok let me see what I can do.

Comment: This is mad helpful, and is exactly what I am looking for. I'll look into numpy once I am done with this project. Thank you my dude!

Comment: To re-clarify for the brackets, is this example correct? ```rolled_nums = []", ".join(str(i) for i in list(rolled_nums))```?

Comment: In the "random" example use `", ".join(str(i) for i in rolled_nums)` inside the format() function so `print("You rolled {} dices. The numbers are {}.".format(num_dice, ", ".join(str(i) for i in rolled_nums)))`. join() takes the list of strings which is formed by the `str(i) for i in rolled_nums` and joins each element while separating them by ", "

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean by:

```
print("You rolled", sum(number), "dices. The numbers are", random.sample(range(50), 12), ".")
```

Comment: Yes, but I am looking for more a detailed one.
Do I do this as the end result? 
```print("You rolled " + number + " dice.  The numbers are" + numbers + ".")```

Comment: Ok, I tested this out and got this result: ```You rolled  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  dice.  The numbers are [21, 8, 26, 23, 39, 35, 42, 37, 40, 34, 16, 27] .``` what do I do about the ```nums=[1, 2, 3, 5, 6]```? Also, was wondering if there was a way to hide the brackets for the range?

Comment: If you want to keep the numbers within the range corresponding to the number of edges on the die, check out my answer. @U10-Forward's answer gives unique numbers according to your question and doesn't take into account the number of edges or what happens in reality when you throw many dice - that is there will be repetition in numbers.

Comment: @lbragile Sorry, realized must be someone else since both of our answers are downvoted